# Next buffer command change when in the terminal window

Tags: buffers, help

I am totally new to Emacs and on this first day I am trying to do very basic stuff in emacs. I am stuck at switching buffers when there is a terminal window open (by using `M-x term`). The next buffer command changes from `<XF86Forward>` to `C-c C-<right>`. I tried to type `Ctrl + c + Ctrl + ->` on the keyboard, but it still doesn't work. What is the problem here?

P.S. I am using macOS Mojave and Emacs 26.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C-<right>` (sometimes written `<C-right>`) means press and hold the Control key while hitting the `<right>` key. The `<right>` key is the right-arrow key.

Emacs key notation is described here: [(emacs) User Input](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/User-Input.html).

You can get to that doc within Emacs, by doing this: `C-h r i keyboard input`.

That is:

1. Use `C-h` (Control + h) followed by `r` to visit the Emacs manual.
2. Use `i` followed by inputting the text `keyboard input`.

In a manual, `i` looks things up in the Index. Looking up `keyboard input` it puts you in the manual node **User Input**.

Comment: I tried doing it but no new line showing `C-c C-<right>` on the Message buffer, while `C-c s-<right>` can be produced when I held and pressed the command key for `s` on mac. Why doesn't my `C-<right>` work?

Comment: Found the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/638697/in-emacs-my-c-right-and-c-left-on-my-mac-keyboard-does-not-work). After deselect these shortcuts I can use this command. Thanks a lot!